# Xcode - Using #pragma mark

Tags: xcode, pragma

I'm pretty sure this isn't a duplicate.
Do you use #pragma mark? I've seen multiple ways, which is correct?

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Actions ===
#pragma mark -

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Actions ===

#pragma mark - === Actions ===

#pragma mark Actions
```

What is the way you do it?
How do you suggest dividing it up? What do you normally name your sections, for say, a view controller?

Comment: Incidentally, if you type pm then hit control-period, it will insert `#pragma mark`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no "Correct" way, it is annotation, so how you use it is a coding style issue.

Having said that, I do:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Actions
```

Because that causes the popup menu in the Xcode editor group the title and the methods inside of the same divider.

Comment: As of Xcode 4, it can be written on a single line: `#pragma mark - Actions`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326343/what-is-the-pragma-mark-substitute-in-strings-file-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

if use like this

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Actions
```

or this

```
#pragma mark - Actions
```

xcode will add one separator and bold text line Actions.

*BUT* if you add one more space after minus - xcode will create two separators one by one...

```
#pragma mark -SPACEHERE
#pragma mark Actions
```

:)