# What is the pragma mark substitute in .strings file in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

`#pragma mark -` works with .h files. What to use in a .strings file to achieve the same?

Comment: I would like to know the answer too, if there is any. Comment isn't enough in a large string files.

Comment: i think there is no solution for this besides using comments. Comments have another color. You can part your stringfile in multiple ones

Comment: still it would be good to know as it will help alot in a multi langugage project with a ton of strings

Comment: #pragma mark could be done in .strings file. see this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062604/is-it-possible-mark-pragma-mark-in-localizable-string-file

Answer (score 1):

A `.strings` file is basically a plist file with a special format. That is, it's NOT an input file for the compiler. That also means, a `#pragma` isn't allowed in a plist.

AFAIK, plist only allows C-style comments beyond the core grammar. You can check a plist file for valid syntax with the `plutil` tool using the `-lint` option.

Comment: .strings file is not .plist file. It's got nothing to do with XML. It's plain old text file with strings in it.

Comment: @Desdenova not all property lists are XML. See "Old-Style ASCII Property Lists" - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html