# Is it Possible MARK: (#pragma mark) in Localizable.string file

Tags: ios, swift, pragma, localizable.strings

Pragma mark not working in **Localizable.strings** file. If I add second `MARK:` (#pragma mark) in **Localizable.strings**, xcode rise compile time error

```
error: read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

See below Image, When I was added the first pragma mark `// MARK: MENU ITEMS`, it didn't show any error. But when I add the second mark `// MARK: EMAIL SETTINGS` it shows the above error.

[image]

My intention is simple, Localizable.strings should be in organized ordered like below.

[image]

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326343/what-is-the-pragma-mark-substitute-in-strings-file-in-xcode) didn't clear my doubt and not get detail explanation and it's too old too. So if anyone experienced this, please give your answers/suggestion.

Comment: Well, you are missing a couple of semi-colons (which are required). It couldn't be as simple as that, could it? I'm asking cause I'm using // MARK in my localizable files all the time with no problem...

Comment: The ideal solution is to split the `Localizable.strings` file into multiple files. You don't have to put everyting into a single file.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, you are right. I've split module wise and more files are there. The above are only related to Settings module. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible.**

You're missing a few required semi-colons. I guess it is used for string-termination or similar under the hood...

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

Comment: I'll check and let you know.