# In Xcode, How do I Suppress "MARK:" part of menu addition?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, pragma

In Objective C, when using

```
// MARK: Line In Sand
```

The default project will produce a menu items with the word "MARK:" in it, or in other words:

[image: Line In Sand showing MARK]

Just recently I downloaded a sample project in Swift (vs ObjC) "ViewControllerPreview" from Apple and the // MARK: Line In Sand only showed "Line In Sand" (no "MARK") when using the aforementioned mark comment style.  How'd they do that!?  Is that just a basic improvement not applied to anything but Swift?

[image: Mark not in menu!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, you can make a mark like that in two different ways:

```
#pragma mark - Hack

// MARK: HACK
```

This will appear like so:

[image: mark]

In Swift, you only get `// MARK`, which is treated like a pragma mark.

```
// MARK: Something
```

[image: Swift mark]

Comment: Ok, that's what I was afraid of.  Only in Swift. #pragma adds to the syntax mess of ObjC files. Cleaner with Swift only apparently.

Comment: Very aware of #pragma. Question was specifically if the clean "MARK" menu result for Objective C could be achieved through some plist hack in Xcode or a setting buried in the myriad project settings. Like many others, not keen on the #pragma workarounds and how it makes the already fairly messy (sorry) ObjC code even messier. Was hoping for some nifty preprocessor settings hack :->

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Objective-C, use this syntax:

```
#pragma mark Line In Sand
```

Comment: This question is not about Objective-C, it's about Swift.

Comment: According to his first screenshot, he's looking at this file:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Listings/CustomRightView_CustomRightViewController_m.html, so please remove your down vote.

Comment: He appears using the Swift syntax in an Obj-C file, which is how you will see that result in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10 now handles the Objective C and Swift use of

```
// MARK: - Line In Sand
```

identically so this question and answer have finally been rendered moot by an Apple update.

(fate of original answer below left to community)

<s>It turns out that the pre-processor in Swift makes special allowance for the</s>

```
// MARK:
```

syntax, while the Objective C pre-processor sees this and makes no allowance for special handling.  This could be alleviated by Apple by omitting the "MARK:" from the menu just as is done with the #pragma version but no joy.

And on a related note, it turns out the Swift (not ObjC) pre-processor also knows how to add a divider line in automatically so:

```
// MARK: - Line In Sand
```

produces not only a divider line but the 'markless' menu item as well... but only in Swift.

[image: Swift preprocessor cleans up 'MARK' where as ObjC does not]

Comment: The line can be added by just adding a `#pragma mark -` before your `#pragma mark Line In Sand`.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1230904/2415822).

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8.3, Apple finally fixed `// MARK:` convention for marking sections of code in Objective C so it no longer showed the word "MARK" in the menu.

The Objective C  `#pragma mark -` was inconsistent with other code marking mechanisms such as `// ???:` , `// !!!:` , `// FIXME:` , and others. The fact that `// MARK:` was implemented cleanly in Swift and half-implemented in ObjC was inconsistent in Xcode itself until Xcode fixed the implementation for `// MARK:` in the editor for ObjC.

With Xcode 8.3

```
// MARK: - Line In Sand
```

works in Objective C properly and no longer shows the "MARK" artifact in the menu.